# Split phases of the election into different Community Bulletin events

Tags: feature-request, election, community-bulletin

The bulletin treats the election as one big thing, ending when the election is over:

[image]

But really there are three phases; nomination, primary (optional) and election. It's not something you just visit once. I think the Nom, Primary and Election should each have their own items with their own end times, only showing the current phase on the bulletin.

If they were split out I would know "Oh, it's nomination so I should go nominate myself!" or "Hey, it's voting time!". This would make it much easier to know when I need to pop in for each part of the election. If I pop in for the nom, I might be annoyed that I can't vote, and forget when it's time for the actual vote.

Comment: Yes, 99 notifications isn't enough!

Comment: @BenBrocka I can see when this may be easier. I think that this would be useful thing for elections.